# Inverse of $2 \times 2$ block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> [image: The link about his simple inverse equation]

I find this simple equation, curious about how the last two equalities derived? Can anybody share some insights about this?

Comment: By-block operations are performed as if the blocks were single elements, replacing sums, products and divisions of scalars by sum, products and products with the inverse of matrices. But mind the order, products are no more commutative.

Comment: You could use Kronecker products (the block matrix is a Kronecker product of a 2x2 matrix and an identity matrix) and then use the Kronecker inversion rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Relations_to_other_matrix_operations

Answer (score 0):

Write out the block matrix in terms of its elements and perform Gauss-Jordan elimination to obtain the inverse matrix, which obtains your result.